# Highlight specific word "nottingham" in a cell range - Need formula

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I need help highlighting a specific word from G7 to G31. The conditional formatting needs to create a yellow highlight when the First word in the subdivision of rows 7-31 matches the first word of the value in G2 "Nottingham".

Tried to use **=$G2="Nottingham"** but it is not working...

[image]

Also tried **=regexmatch(G7,"(?i)^"&regexextract(G$2,"\w"))** but this formula is matching too loosely. there sample entries I made are too different than G2 to be considered a close match.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `G7:G`:

```
=regexmatch( G7, "(?i)^" & regexextract(G$2, "\w+") )
```

Comment: Tried to use your formula, however, this formula is matching too loosely. there sample entries I made are too different than G2 to be considered a close match. I've edited my post for the pic

Comment: Use `\w+` instead of `\w`.